# How can i store all these codes in a variable

Tags: javascript

How can i keep all these codes in a variable? I want to call this codes in another place. I want to add a click event on this slideShow menu. It's easy if i write all those codes in another click event function. But i don't want to do that, i want to call all this codes in a click event by uscing a variable

```
function change() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[0].classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[1].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[0].classList.remove("active");
  } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[1].classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[2].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[1].classList.remove("active");

  } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[2].classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[3].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[2].classList.remove("active");

  } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[3].classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[4].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[3].classList.remove("active");

  } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[4].classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[1].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("sliderItems")[4].classList.remove("active");
  }
}
setInterval(change, 2000);
```

Comment: *i want to call this codes in many places.* Its a function. Just call it

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: please read this and edit your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and after edit the question. Because the question is unclear.

Comment: i want to add a click event on this slideShow menu. it's easy if i write all those codes in another click event function .But i don't want to do that, i want to call all this codes in a click event by uscing a variable

Comment: @Arefinbabu is there any problem calling this function on another click event?

Comment: like this `$('button').click(function(){ change() });`

Comment: You mean you have multiple buttons in a single page and you want to bind their click to this `change` function?

Comment: no, i can call this codes in another click event function, and it's working, but the problem is i need to write all this code once again in click event function. i don't want to write this code once again, but i still want to call this code in a click event function. is it possible?

Comment: where is your another click button on same page or different page??

Comment: you are very unclear in your way of explaination, let us discuss this in a chat room

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186092/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-54017783-how-can-i-store-all-these-codes-in-a

Comment: Actually my slideItems is a click button, i use the images as a click button, and i keep this image in a class in the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just assign `setInterval(change, 2000)` to a variable  and use it

add to your script

```
var listenChange = setInterval(change, 2000)
```

use it in your html

```
<button onclick="listenChange()">Button1</Button>
```

Comment: it's my pleasure

Comment: <div class="sliderContainer" onclick="change()">


that's it! OMG this was too easy :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure what you mean with codes, I think you mean the array of sliderItems, if this is what you mean is very easy.

```
var sliderItems = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderItems');

sliderItems[0].classList.add('active');
```

The big advantage of using a variable to store a DOM element is better performance than searching the element every single time you want to use it.